# Как с помощью рефлексии обойти все поля сущности, которая разделена на несколько классов, то есть и поля в классах-предках

Tags: java, наследование, рефлексия

У меня есть сущность разделенная на несколько классов

```
public abstract class OneBaseAbstract {

    private Long id;

    private String name;

    public OneBaseAbstract() {
    }

...

}
```

2-й

```
public abstract class TwoBaseAbstract extends OneBaseAbstract{

    private Integer num;

    private String mark;

    public TwoBaseAbstract() {
        super();
    }
...
}
```

3-й

```
public class Produce extends TwoBaseAbstract {

    private String name2;

    private String product;

    public Produce() {
        super();
    }
...
}
```

Поля в сущностях в несколько десятков и таблиц много, для тестирования чтобы заполнить вручную, много времени и много ошибок может быть.
 Я автоматизировал создание объекта, но это работает только на класс, который не имеет предка.

Вот класс, который разбирает объект, наполняет его произвольными данными.

```
/**класс утилит для заполнения значений поля объекта*/
public final class FieldProcessForFillUtils {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(FieldProcessForFillUtils.class);
    private static final String LOGGER_MESSAGE_DATA_TYPE = "The data type is not defined here.";

    /**
     *  Заполнение полей объекта.
     * @param object - обрабатываемый объект, любого типа данных
     * @param values - коллекция значений, которые будут сгенерированы для полей обрабатываемого объекта
     * @param <S> - универсальный параметр, указывает на тип данных передаваемого объекта
     * @return  - возвращает обработанный объект. S - универсальный параметр, хранит информацию об текущем
     *            обрабатываемом объекте
     */
    public static  <S> S fillData (S object, List<Object> values){

        return obtainMetadataOfObject(object, values);
    }


    /**
     * Извлечение метаданных из полученного объекта, для дальнейшей обработки
     * @param object - обрабатываемый объект
     * @param values - коллекция значений, которые будут сгенерированы для полей обрабатываемого объекта
     * @param <S> - универсальный параметр, указывает на тип данных передаваемого объекта
     * @return - возвращает обработанный объект. S - универсальный параметр, хранит информацию об текущем
     * обрабатываемом объекте
     */
    private static <S> S obtainMetadataOfObject(S object, List<Object> values){

        Class<?> objectClass = object.getClass();
        Field[] fields = objectClass.getDeclaredFields();

        parseArrFields(fields, object, values);

        return object;
    }

    /**парсинг массива полей*/
    private static void parseArrFields(Field [] fields, Object object, List<Object> values){

        for(Field field : fields){
            Class<?> type = field.getType();
            String typeName = type.getSimpleName();

            setValue(field, typeName, object, values);
        }

    }

    /**
     *
     * @param field - поле для изменения
     * @param typeName - имя типа данных текущего поля
     * @param object - объект, поле которого обрабатываются на текущий момент
     * @param values - коллекция , куда будут заносится сгенерированные значения,
     *               которые будут установлены  в обрабатываемые поля текущего объекта
     */
    private static void setValue(Field field, String typeName, Object object, List<Object> values){

        Integer yearMin = 2017;
        Integer yearMax = 2019;

        Long minLimitForRandom = 1L;
        Long maxLimitForRandom = 200000L;

        switch (typeName){

            case "Long" : /* тип данных*/
                field.setAccessible(true);
                try {
                    Double aDouble = randomNumberGenerator(maxLimitForRandom , minLimitForRandom);
                    Long id = aDouble.longValue();

                    field.set(object, id);
                    values.add(id);

                } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                break;

            case "Integer":
                field.setAccessible(true);
                try {

                    Integer number = randomNumberGenerator(maxLimitForRandom, minLimitForRandom).intValue();
                    field.set(object, number);
                    values.add(number);

                } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                break;

            case "String":
                field.setAccessible(true);
                try {
                    String randomStr = generatingRandomStringAlphabetic();
                    field.set(object, randomStr);
                    values.add(randomStr);

                } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                break;

            case "LocalDate":


                field.setAccessible(true);
                LocalDate localDate = generatorLocalDate(yearMin, yearMax);
                try {
                    field.set(object, localDate);
                    values.add(localDate);
                } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                break;

            case "LocalDateTime":

                field.setAccessible(true);

                LocalDateTime localDateTime = generatorLocalDateTime(yearMin, yearMax);

                try {
                    field.set(object, localDateTime);
                    values.add(localDateTime);
                } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                break;

            case "Character":
                field.setAccessible(true);
                Character character = generateRandomSpecialCharacters();

                try {
                    field.set(object, character);
                    values.add(character);
                } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                break;

            default:
                LOGGER.error(LOGGER_MESSAGE_DATA_TYPE);

        }

    }

}
```

Данный код, когда всречает объект разделенный на несколько классов, видит только поля класса-потомка.

Что можно в коде подправить, чтобы  массив **Field[] fields**

```
 Field[] fields = objectClass.getDeclaredFields();
```

получил все поля, в том числе и поля классов-предков

решил так

```
 private static <S> void obtainMetadataOfObject(S object, List<Object> values) {

    Class<?> objectClass = object.getClass();

    Field[] fields;

    Class superClazz = objectClass.getSuperclass();

    String nameObjectClass = "Object";

    String simpleNameObjectExpected = superClazz.getSimpleName();

    boolean isObjectClass = Objects.equals(simpleNameObjectExpected, nameObjectClass);


    if(!isObjectClass){

        List<Field> allFields = getAllFields(objectClass);
        fields = convertCollectionToArray(allFields);
    } else {
        fields = objectClass.getDeclaredFields();
    }

    compareLengthArrays(fields.length, values.size());

    parseArrFields(fields, object, values);

}


/**
 * Обработка полей составного класса, используется рефлексия
 * @param clazz - тип объекта
 * @return - возвращает список полей составного класса
 */
private static List<Field> getAllFields(Class clazz) {

    List<Field> fields = Arrays.asList(clazz.getDeclaredFields());

    List<Field> fieldList = new ArrayList<>(fields);

    Class superClazz = clazz.getSuperclass();
    if(superClazz != null){

        fieldList.addAll(getAllFields(superClazz));
    }


    return fieldList ;
}

/** Преобразование коллекции в массив
 * Field[]::new - указывает на то, что каждый элемент коллекции нужно
 * передать в конструктор класса Field и после создания экземпляра, данный экземпляр
 * добавляется в указанный тип массива*/
private static Field[] convertCollectionToArray(List<Field> fields){

    Stream<Field> fieldStream = fields.stream();

    return fieldStream.toArray(Field[]::new);

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Обходим рекурсивно `objectClass.getSuperclass()`

```java
    public static Field[] getAllFields(Object o){
        System.out.println("Get all fields from Object");
        Class<?> c = o.getClass();
        Field[] fields = {};
        while (c!=null){
            fields = ArrayUtils.addAll(fields, c.getDeclaredFields());
            c = c.getSuperclass();
        }
        return fields;
    }
```

Склейка массивов не оптимальна ;)